# How to create a poly line that fills below (WPF)

Tags: wpf, fill, polyline

I'm experimenting with shapes in C#/WPF. In a window I create a Polyline with some Points assigned to it:

```
<Window x:Class="PolylineTest.MainWindow"       
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Polyline">
      <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Polyline Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"
              FillRule="Nonzero" Points="1, 99 2, 99 3, 99 4, 99 5, 99
              6, 99 7, 99 8, 99 9, 98 10, 98 11, 98 12, 98 13, 98 14, 98
              15, 98 16, 98 17, 98 18, 98 19, 98 20, 97 21, 96 22, 96
              23, 96 24, 96 25, 96 26, 96 27, 96 28, 96 29, 96 30, 96
              31, 96 32, 95 33, 96 34, 94 35, 94 36, 94 37, 93 38, 93
              39, 94 40, 93 41, 92 42, 93 43, 92 44, 91 45, 91 46, 91
              47, 90 48, 89 49, 88 50, 87 51, 86 52, 85 53, 85 54, 83
              55, 83 56, 84 57, 86 58, 86 59, 85 60, 85 61, 83 62, 81
              63, 77 64, 80 65, 83 66, 78 67, 80 68, 77 69, 72 70, 78
              71, 74 72, 76 73, 80 74, 78 75, 81 76, 78 77, 74 78, 73
              79, 71 80, 73 81, 67 82, 74 83, 77 84, 73 85, 71 86, 74
              87, 74 88, 71 89, 72 90, 72 91, 76 92, 72 93, 67 94, 68
              95, 71 96, 72 97, 73 98, 73 99, 74 100, 76 101, 76 102, 77
              103, 74 104, 78 105, 77 106, 69 107, 68 108, 68 109, 65
              110, 73 111, 71 112, 73 113, 76 114, 66 115, 66 116, 72
              117, 73 118, 73 119, 77 120, 73 121, 73 122, 75 123, 77
              124, 73 125, 76 126, 79 127, 74 128, 72 129, 74 130, 76
              131, 73 132, 76 133, 76 134, 70 "/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

This gives the following output:

[image: Current polyline output]

But what I want to achieve is that only the area below the polyline is filled. Like this:
[image: Wanted polyline output]

Using the `FillRule`property is not helpful here. Is there any way to do it (with polyLine) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to draw a filled Path element below the non-filled Polyline, where the Path's Data contains a Geometry that includes the points from the Polyline plus the desired corner points:

```
<Canvas Margin="20">
    <Path Fill="Red">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="1,100">
                    <PolyLineSegment Points="{Binding Points, ElementName=polyline}"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="134,100"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Polyline x:Name="polyline"
        Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeLineJoin="Round"
        StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
        Points="1,99 .. 134,70"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: I had to open the Path with `<Path Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="21" Canvas.Top="20">` and then it worked. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Or just set the same Margin as you do on the Polyline. Or better, *remove* the Margin from the Polyline and put it on the Canvas. See the edited answer.